# uncaught rootscope:infdig error when using ng repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying this for sometime but not able to resolve this error.

I call a function `parseBug` in ng-repeat. This function modifies two fields and converts them into an array. The problem arrives when I try to return the array. I get an error

> Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

When i try and print the same array in console it prints without any problems.

I did try searching about the issue but i'm not sure about how digest works

HTML:

```
<a data-ng-repeat="a in parseBug(auditdata)">{{a.bugs}}<br></a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.parseBug= function (auditdata) { 

            var data = new Array ();

            var bugnumber = auditdata.bugnumber;
            var comment = auditdata.comment;
            if (bugnumber !=null || comment !=null)
                {
                    var bugs = new Array ();
                    var comm = new Array ();
                    bugs = bugnumber.substring(1,bugnumber.length-1).replace(/['"]+/g,'').split(",");
                    comm = comment.substring(1,comment.length-1).replace(/['"]+/g,'').split(",");
                    for ( i=0; i < bugs.length;i++) {

                        var dict ={};
                        dict["bugs"]= bugs[i];
                        dict["comment"]=comm[i];

                        data.push(dict);
                    }               
                }

            return data;
      };
```

How the fields look in db:

```
"bugnumber" : [
                "123",
                "4567"
        ],
        "comment" : [
                "test",
                "again"
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the angular docs about [$rootScope / infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)

> One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new
>   array every time it is called. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>

...

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];
};
```

> Since getUsers() returns a new array, Angular determines that the
>   model is different on each $digest cycle, resulting in the error.The
>   solution is to return the same array object if the elements have not
>   changed:

```
var users = [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return users;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

parseBug is returning a new array every single time you call it. Thats the problem. Either evaluate it once in your controller, and then ng-repeat on the result of that evaluation, or assign the array value to a scope variable, and only create a new array if the scope variable hasn't already been created.